# Triggering div in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to handle a `click` event on a `div` element:

```
$("#id").on('mousedown', function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

But this `div` element contains another `div` (let's call it `#id2`) with clickable parts. How can I prevent the `mousedown` event from firing, if the user clicks on `#id2`? Right now, when I click on `#id2`, `mousedown('#id')` and `onclick('#id2')` will trigger.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Which `div` do you want to receive the event on, the outer `#id` or the inner `#id2`?

Comment: `mousedown` and `click` are **differrent** events

Comment: use `stopPropagation()` .. https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) so that `id2`'s `click` event does not also fire the `mousedown` event for `id`. At the same time, it appears that `mousedown` will fire anyways when `id2` is clicked, so you can check [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)'s `id` property to avoid executing code when `id2` is clicked. Here's a quick example:

```js
$("#id").on('mousedown', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id === 'id2') {
    console.log('Mousedown evet fired from id2, aborting...');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Mousedown on id');

});

$("#id2").on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Click on id2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
  ID 1
  <div id="id2">
    ID 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Question: `event.stopPropagation()` "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event" but here the parent is the target element, then setting `stopPropagation` to the child will prevent propagation to its children, is that so? I mean the `event.target.id === 'id2'` test in mandatory here right?

Comment: stopPropagation "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event." I didn't even used that. Checking target's id/classList fits me

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using jQuery, you can attach a `mousedown` listener to the inner div, then return `false` from it:

```js
$("#inner").click(function() {
  console.log("inner div was clicked");
  return false;
}).on("mousedown", function() {
  console.log("mousedown propagation stops here");
  return false;
});
$("#outer").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  console.log("outer div mousedown")
});
```

```css
#outer {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner {
  height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```